# Refreshing lxsession kodi-standalone exit

Tags: raspbian-stretch, systemd-unit

I'm having difficulties refreshing a screen after kodi-standalone exits. I have a stretch-lite RPI2 installation and starting kodi from command line (with LXDE xserver gui present)

```
mrkipi@raspberrypi:~ $kodi-standalone
```

When started from command line like above (and exited from kodi) my display refreshes normally and I can see the screen as before the kodi start.

On the other hand I have prepared a simple service (which would not run on boot) to start the kodi-standalone

```
[Unit]
Description = Kodi Media Center
After = systemd-user-sessions.service network-online.target sound.target
Wants = systemd-user-sessions.service network-online.target sound.target

[Service]
User = mrkipi
Group = pi
Type = simple
ExecStart = /usr/bin/kodi-standalone
ExecStopPost = /bin/sleep 10
ExecStopPost = /usr/bin/xrefresh
Restart = never

[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

Starting kodi-standalone via this simple service on the other hand does NOT refresh the sceen after kodi exit - but I'd like to do so, therefore I wanted to call

```
ExecStopPost = /usr/bin/xrefresh
```

to refresh the lxsession. While this WORKS from the command line

```
mrkipi@raspberrypi:~ $xrefresh
```

the service execution gives

```
kodi.service - Kodi Media Center
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/kodi.service; disabled; vendor preset: en
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2019-11-17 23:27:40 CET; 31s ago
  Process: 1792 ExecStopPost=/usr/bin/xrefresh (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 1786 ExecStopPost=/bin/sleep 10 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1681 ExecStart=/usr/bin/kodi-standalone (code=killed, signal=TERM)
 Main PID: 1681 (code=killed, signal=TERM)
```

On the other hand `ExecStopPost=/bin/sleep 10` works without a problem within the servicestoppost.

How can I refresh the screen within the ExecStopPost OR by executing some other script, which I could also call?

Is this only a problem of TTY not beeing available in the time of ExecStopPost, because the command line xrefresh is working without problems?

Comment: Maybe `xrefresh` gives additional info why it fails? Can you please edit your question (the button below it) and replace the service output with the complete output of `systemctl status kodi.service`. Isn't there already a `kodi.service` from the installation of kodi?

Comment: Try using `xrefresh -display :0` (presuming you are only running one instance of `Xorg`).

Comment: Hi Ingo.Thanks for your reply first.Yes there is a kodi.service already provided, but up to my knowledge for the libreelec, openelec distributions, but i'm using stretch lite with kodi standalone, where there was none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proposed solution from goldilocks (thanks) works like a charm with single xorg instance:

```
xrefresh -display :0
```

Looking at it again it is also clear to say which display to refresh.